# Accessing a dictionary from angular controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do the following.

Angular controller calls and MVC controller GET method. This method then calls into a REST API on the web which returns a list of configuration items. I then turn this into a dictionary so I can look up configuration values based on the key, and then I want to pass this back to the Angular controller and store it there in a variable that I can access from many different scenarios, eg displaying them in grids, updating values, changing and updating them back to the REST API etc. I have tried to set up the pipes but I can't seem to get the data in a readable/usable format in the Angular controller.

My controller

```
app.controller("SEFlexHomeController", ["$scope", "$http", "$modal", "$log", "$element", "$rootScope", "AlertsService", "AuthService", "SEApplicationService", function ($scope, $http, $modal, $log, $element, $rootScope, AlertsService, AuthService, SEApplicationService) {
        $rootScope.closeAlert = AlertsService.closeAlert;
        $scope.isDataLoading = false;
        $scope.AuthService = AuthService;
        $scope.configvalues = angular.fromJson(SEApplicationService.getCloudConfigParams());
    }
]);
```

My Angular Service

```
app.factory("SEApplicationService", ["$log", "$http", "$timeout", function($log, $http, $timeout) {

    var appService = {};    

    appService.getCloudConfigParams = function () {
        return $http.get("/SEFlex/SEFlexAdmin/GetCloudConfigValues");
    }

    return appService;
}]);
```

My MVC controller

```
public ActionResult GetCloudConfigValues()
        {
            try
            {
                var helper = new ApplicationServiceHelper();
                var dictionary = helper.GetCloudConfigValues()
                    .ToList()
                    .ToDictionary(item => item.ConfigKey, item => item.ConfigValue);

                var returnData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);

                return Json(new
                {
                    success = true,
                    data = returnData
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    success = false,
                    errors = new[] { exception.Message }
                });
            }
        }
```

I can confirm at the time of creating the Dictionary in the MVC controller, the dictionary looks as expected for a .NET dictionary. What do I need to do to convert this either before transmission back or back in Angular, so that I can access it in angular as

> $scope.configvalues["keyName"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`$http.get()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) call returns [a promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api). You should change the

```
$scope.configvalues = angular.fromJson(SEApplicationService.getCloudConfigParams());
```

to

```
SEApplicationService.getCloudConfigParams().then(function(config) {
    $scope.configvalues = config;
});
```

Comment: So it's effectively an asynch call and this is angulars way of doing a continuation when the async completes? Will this cause trouble for my HTML which depends on the value of configvalues to populate the view, or will the databinding be ok with this?

Comment: Yes, promises are commonly used in Angular apps. However, it is not only Angular concept. If you want to be sure that the value is present before the view is rendered, use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), i.e. `<div ng-if="configvalues">your view</div>`